# WP7:LivesmoothStreaming is not working with device

Tags: windows-phone-7, live-streaming

We're building a LIVE Smooth Streaming WP7 App.It works perfectly on the emulator, but not on device (shows up blank).

We are also trying smf player for streaming on WP7 but every time we are getting a blank screen on player. Its only work on Emulator.
Though there is no error being thrown.

How i can apply live streaming on my windows phone not on emulator.

looking for your responce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your streaming source contain multi-resolution tracks?

This kind of problem may appear when testing on a WP8 Emulator and then deploying the app to a WP7 device. Specially if the WP7 device is a first-generation device, like HTC HD7.

Basically this happens because the WP8 emulator and Wp8 devices do support multi-resolution, but old devices do not support multi-resolution tracks. You can read more here: http://blog.supaywasi.com/2013/01/smooth-streaming-multi-resolution-support-for-windows-phone/

So, basically you have to handle the [ManifestReady](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.media.smoothstreaming.smoothstreamingmediaelement.manifestready.aspx) event on your WP7 app and [RestrictTracks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.media.smoothstreaming.streaminfo.restricttracks.aspx) to only tracks of the same resolution. 
For WP8 devices you will not need to this.

Comment: :Yes my streaming source contain multi-resolution tracks.and i have wp7 emulator.

Comment: :thanks now my video player is working on device also.ANd this is through RestrictTracks method.

Comment: @user1774180 Great! For the future, please consider that your users may use your app on WP8 devices, which are capable of streaming multi-resolution tracks. Hence, you will need to implement a different logic so you could deliver the best image quality based on device capabilities.

Comment: :thanks for giving me such kind of information,But how can i manage this logic for diffrent deveice(i.e wp8 or wp7)